# Can't start a new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Ubuntu, I install Android Studio , but when I click "Start a new project" , it open. I fill up "Target Android Device". Then problem, it not work. No  'Next' option. I tried reinstalling, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Tick the devices you are targeting and be sure you have an SDK!

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of menu where you have no Next option? I think you did not select the target device or did not fill in the project name/company domain.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of project creation step window where you have problems (no next option)